# Ubuntu 10.04 task-bar content not right aligned in virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, gnome, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 in VirtualBox. 
I installed the guest additions.
My display resolution is set to 1920x1080

For some reason, my task-bar content doesn't right align. Have a look at the picture below:

[image]

Is there any fix for this?

*P.S - I am using Ubuntu 10.04 because I need the Linux kernel version to be 2.6*